# Why can't a Boolean be converted to Visibility in a Binding without having to supply a BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, boolean, visibility

It seem strange that a binding can't convert a boolean to visibility by default without having to supply a BooleanToVisibilityConverter everytime everywhere. Anyone know why?

**Update**

I've found a way to do this now:

Create a TypeConverter like this:

```
public class VisibilityFromBooleanConverter : TypeConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
  {
    if (sourceType == typeof(Boolean)) return true;
    return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
  }

  public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
  {
    if (value is Boolean) return ((Boolean)value) ? Visibility.Visible :
      Visibility.Collapsed;
    return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
  }
```

}

And add this to your app:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Visibility),
  new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(VisibilityFromBooleanConverter)));
```

It seem to work just fine. Now you don't have to supply a BooleanToVisibilityConverter for every boolean-binding.

Comment: +1 Very nice, Learned something usefull here.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible Visibilities:

1. `Visible`
2. `Hidden`
3. `Collapsed`

How do you convert something with two states to something with three?

Comment: Andreas... you should had seen this coming :o) Unless you're really talking about Silverlight.

Comment: I kinda did. But I mean the desired behaviour is 99 times out of 100 that you want true to be visible and false to be collapsed. Why not have that as default and let the developer provide a converter if he/she want it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Because boolean and visiblitiy don't have the same type in the back. 
And there are 2 states which are not visible -> "hidden" and "collapsed". Based on what should WPF decide what you want?

Comment: It can convert doubles to strings even though there are many ways of converting a double to a string...